# Laravel 4 custom unique validation multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm coming across this problem regarding validating a unique permalink for a blog post that is created by a certain user. The schema:

```
users: `id`, `username`

posts: `id`, `title`, `permalink`

users_posts: `id`, `user_id`, `post_id`
```

Now when a user submits new blog post, he has to select a unique permalink for his post, but this permalink should just be unique for him only (meaning another user can use that permalink as long as that permalink is unique amongst that user's posts).

How could I use Laravel validator to do this? I suspect there's any built in validator so I have to roll out my own validator, but I'm not even sure how to write a query to check this.

Can somebody show me a query string that helps solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If a post have only one author, you should'nt use a third table. And so, you should put user_id id posts table and add the following constraint to posts table: `UNIQUE ( permalink, user_id )`

If your posts can have several authors, your permalink system cannot works like this.